# Functions returning functions understanding why it works

Tags: javascript

```js
function retirement(retirementAge) {
  var a = ' years left until retirement.';
  return function(yearOfBirth) {
    var age = 2016 - yearOfBirth;
    console.log((retirementAge - age) + a);
  }
}

var retirementUS = retirement(66);
retirementUS(1990);
```

My question is why `yearOfBirth` can be equal to `retirementUS`
I understand this works I just don't understand why.

Comment: *"My question is why `yearOfBirth` can be equal to `retirementUS`"* wait, who says that? they're not equal at all, one is a function and the other one is a number passed to that function.

Answer (score 0):

the return value of `retirement` is a function.
Since functions are „First-class citizens” in JavaScript, you can assign a function to a variable (or return it from another function).

You assign the return value to a variable `retirementUS`. This variable now holds a reference to the anonymous function `function(yearOfBirth)`.

In the last line, you pass an argument into that anonymous function.
Within that one, the argument gets referenced as `yearOfBirth`.

Since it is within the same scope as `retirement`, it has access to `retirementAge`.

Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

1. In JavaScript functions are [first-class citizens](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/First-class_Function), you can **assign** a function to a variable.
2. You `retirement` function is returning another function that you are **assigning** it to a variable you called `retirementUS`.

In your line:

```
var retirementUS = retirement(66);
```

You returned the result of the first function that took `retirementAge` as parameter and returned another anonymous function.

Then you called that anonymous function that you assigned to `retirementUS`:

```
retirementUS(1990);
```

You could also call both functions directly by:

```
retirement(66)(1990)
```

---

```js
function retirement(retirementAge) {
  var a = ' years left until retirement.';
  return function(yearOfBirth) {
    var age = 2016 - yearOfBirth;
    console.log((retirementAge - age) + a);
  }
}

const retirementUS = retirement(60);

// your "retirement" returns another function
console.log(`Type of "retirementUS" is: ${typeof retirementUS}`)

// so you need to call that second function with its yearOfBirth parameter:

retirementUS(1990)
```

Comment: I'm such a beginner so hard to grasp these concepts

Comment: Hi @NoamAris, no worries. We are here to help :) So, I meant by **assign**: Put the return value of a function (it could be a number, a string or even another function) in a variable. And if we assign a function to a variable, we can use it(the variable) as a function as well. Please check this video for example: https://youtu.be/iZLP4qOwY8I, or just look-up for currying in JavaScript, if you still find it confusing check this great playlist: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL0zVEGEvSaeEd9hlmCXrk5yUyqUag-n84

Comment: If you have one equal sign, it means that you are assigning a value, and not checking for equality, and that what confuses people when they first read your question, so you should ask it like this: *My question is why yearOfBirth can be **assigned** (and not "equal")  to retirementUS I understand this works I just don't understand why.*